# How to transform a method call pattern found in multiple methods into a simpler OO mechanism?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods, facade

In my class I have a lot of functions that simply redirect code to a DAO class (a class that forms business objects from data from a database).

Is there a way to maybe create a single function that replaces all of the functions below?

```
public function getIdFromModel($model)
{
    return $this->motorDao->getIdFromModel($model);
}

public function getFrames($a, $b, $c)
{
    return $this->motorDao->getFrames($a, $b, $c);
}

public function getManufacturers()
{
    return $this->motorDao->getManufacturers();
}
```

What is the mechanism to do this and how is it used?

Comment: May be facade pattern solves it

Comment: If your `DAO` object has public class members you *could* simply have a method in your class called something like `getDAO()` which returns `$this->motorDao` (assuming `motorDao` is a private/protected class member) - you can then access the public methods of `motorDao` in your code like this : `$class->getDao()->getIdFromModel($model)` instead of mirroring all the `DAO` methods in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by implementing the [magic method `__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

However, I would strongly recommend against it. Using magic methods is a lot slower, and it's harder for IDEs to display code insight information.

Also, you would still wind up with *almost* as much code, unless you pass everything on without even checking the method name. But if you do that, you have no validation whatsoever and anyone can just call any method of the DAO object. Question then is, why do you have this object inbetween in the first place?

Comment: Sure, `__call` has also drawbacks, but it is great in general! Why not using the benefits of PHP compared to other languages?

Comment: @hek2mgl  I'm not sure I'd call `__call()` a benefit ... more a sort of workaround to the fact that PHP is a loosely typed language and therefore can't do "proper" method overloading.

Comment: @CD001, now you have me curious how to make the same question work but in languages like C++

Comment: With something like Java you can define a class method multiple times and what that method actually does depends on the parameters passed to it (you can kind of fudge it a bit with `func_get_args()` in PHP) - but essentially you could have one method called `foo()` and another called `foo(intFoodId)` another called `foo(strFooName)` or `foo(intFooId, dbConnector)` ... it gives you a clean single point of access through `foo()`  but you've overloaded it to do different things; it could be both a getter and setter for instance depending on whether you pass no params or a `foo` object.

Comment: That's nice for overloads of one method, but getFrames, getModelFromId and getManufacturers seem not to be overloads of each other. This is basically a facade pattern where the facade is the same as the class behind it, so that's why I said *"why do you have this object ..."*. It has no use this way. And besides, the number of methods you want to have is finite, I assume. In the time we all have spend asking, answering and commenting, one could write a number of such wrapper classes.

Comment: @GolezTrol heh, very true :)

Comment: @CD001 `__call()` is not really bound to the term *method overloading* like it is used (and available) in other languages. Take me, I've never used it for that purpose. Also this question is not about *method overloading*. IMHO the term *overloading* which is used by the PHP documentation is misleading. I've added that years ago to the Wikipedia page of PHP :) (Only the German version)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [magic method `__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) for this:

```
public function __call($fname, $args) {
    call_user_func_array(array($this->motorDao, $fname), $args);
}
```

if you just want to redirect a defined set of functions to `motorDao`, use a whitelist:

```
public function __call($fname, $args) {
    if(in_array($fname, array(
        'functionA',
        'functionB',
        '...'
    ))) {
        call_user_func_array(array($this->motorDao, $fname), $args);
    } else {
        throw Exception(sprintf("%s has no method %s",
            get_class($this), $fname
        ));
    }
}
```